# What is the process in which an ArrayList executes?

Tags: java, arraylist

My current lesson in Java is about ArrayLists and I'm having a tough time to understand this bit of code:
This exercise is concerned with the problem of deleting a block of items from an ArrayList.

```
public static void deleteBlock( ArrayList<String> strings, int n )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) // the for loop for checking each index
    {
        if ( strings.size() > 0 ) // if statement to check whether or not the array's size is > 0
            strings.remove( i );  // removes the index of the array at (i)
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    String[] data = { "erosion", "rosion", "osion", "sion", "ion", "on", "n" };  //array being tested
    ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();  
    for ( int i = 0; i < data.length; i++ )
        dataList.add( data[ i ] );

    deleteBlock( dataList, 3 );
    System.out.println( dataList ); // printing out the result
}
```

This is the output: `[rosion, sion, on, n]`

If somebody could please help explain how process behind this code? Thank you!

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: What exactly is not clear here?

Comment: The output is expected to be [ sion, ion, on, n ]  I'm just confused as to how the compiler reads the code, almost as if someone were to add notes as to what is happening throughout each line as it processes.

Comment: Let's do it other way around. Put comments to the parts of the code you **do** understand.

Comment: Please please _please_ just use a debugger to step through your code. It's much easier to look at the variables and watch them change in the debugger as you execute each line than for someone to textually try and explain it to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention to this code (better yet debug!):

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    if ( strings.size() > 0 )
        strings.remove( i );
}
```

What is happening is when `i` = `0`:

> [**"erosion"**, "rosion", "osion", "sion", "ion", "on", "n"] => ["rosion",
>   "osion", "sion", "ion", "on", "n"]

The 0th element was removed.

Then when `i` = `1`:

> ["rosion", **"osion"**, "sion", "ion", "on", "n"] => ["rosion",
>   "sion", "ion", "on", "n"]

The 1st element was removed.

Finally, when `i` = `2`:

> ["rosion", "sion", **"ion"**, "on", "n"] => ["rosion", "sion", "on",
>   "n"]

The 2nd element was removed.

Now, if you want your code just to remove the first 3 elements, then you can do something like:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    if ( strings.size() > 0 )
        strings.remove( 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The block of code you're showing us is apparently meant to show *the problems that can occur when you delete items from a list that you're iterating through at the same time.*

The problem occurs here:

```
public static void deleteBlock( ArrayList<String> strings, int n )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( strings.size() > 0 )
            strings.remove( i ); // Kaplooey.
    }
}
```

Cybernetic Twerk illustrates clearly what happens in his answer: *when you delete an item before your index, your index no longer points to the same item.*

**Moral:** never write code like this.

Sometimes, you can get away with this if you *iterate in reverse,* that is, from the last element to the first, backwards.  Why this works properly is left as an exercise for the reader.

The proper solution is to add only the desired items from the original list to a new list.

Answer (score 0):

Your original list is this on which you call delete and loop it 4 times.
[erosion, rosion, osion, sion, ion, on, n]

then it goto loop and remove list 0 element which is "erosion"
now list become this
[rosion, osion, sion, ion, on, n]

now it remove list 1 element which is "osion" so it become 
[rosion, sion, ion, on, n]

now your list 2 element removed which is "on" so you got result as
[rosion, sion, on, n]

Answer (score 0):

You are removing elements from the ArrayList based on index.  In your example, first you remove the 0 element, but now the resulting list has "rosion", "osion", "sion", "ion", "on", "n", so when you remove the 1 element, that is "osion", leaving "rosion", "sion", "ion", "on", "n", and when you remove the 2 element, you have "rosion", "sion", "on", "n".

You could change your remove(i) to be remove(0).  Or, you could use removeRange, e.g.

```
public static void deleteBlock( ArrayList<String> strings, int n )
{
    if ( strings.size() < n ) strings.clear();
    else strings.removeRange(0, n);
}
```